# Why could an ASP.NET-Core app get the error message "Locking/unlocking file regions is not supported on this platform." when deployed on MacOS?

Tags: macos, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

Our embedded database library uses the `FileStream.Lock(long, long)` method to implement locking.  We have a customer using the .NET Standard 2.0 version of our library in their small ASP.NET-Core Razor Page application who reports that their application is getting a PlatformNotSupportedException "Locking/unlocking file regions is not supported on this platform. Use FileShare on the entire file instead." when deployed on MacOS (but not when deployed on Windows).  I checked with the customer, and it’s on a 2013 Macbook Pro with a fresh up to date Catalina install on APFS.

Surely, locking file regions isn't truly unsupported on MacOS--or else we should be getting a lot more complaints!  So, we're wondering if there's something that could be missing or wrong in a project or the installation that explains the error and would hopefully be correctable.  Or could we somehow be running into a limitation in MacOS that is tighter than other platforms?  We do use some large special values well past the end of most files (which is legal and works fine in most cases), but we already limited these not to exceed the positive range of a signed `Int32` because some platforms apparently map the `long` arguments into `int` values.

Has anyone encountered this error before and solved what was wrong?  Or is there really no way to support file region locking for .NET programs on a Mac?

Comment: Want DB are you using? And what macOS FS is it running on?

Comment: They are using our VistaDB embedded database engine.

Comment: there are several flavors of Mac file system, I would not assume they behave the same as Windows for low level operations

Comment: @Jason, so it might be that the particular file system they are deploying on is the real issue?

Comment: I would assume so.  It could also be some security setting they have enabled.  This is not my area of expertise, but that seems reasonable.  Also see: https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/issues/787

Comment: @Jason, yeah, I saw that page before, I think, but unless I'm missing it, it only seems to solve it by using exclusive mode, which would defeat the point (although valid as a potential temporary workaround).

Comment: .NET Core is open source, you should be able to look at the source to get a clue why this is, or open an issue asking for explanations/workarounds

Comment: @RobParker File locking is different from Windows to *nix/macOS. Typically you are looking at multi-process access vs multi-threaded access and on macOS files not "hard locked", locks are only advisory (just like any *nix system).

Comment: @SushiHangover, I suppose that's true, but there would presumably be some way of supporting .NET's version of FileShare and file region locking or else .NET apps relying on such primitives would not really be able to work properly on MacOS, Linux, or Unix.  In this particular case, we really only need the Lock() call to correctly hold exclusivity against another Lock() call; it doesn't matter whether it also prevents access.  However, an "unsupported" exception is not helpful.

Comment: @RobParker You can look through the dotnet source/issues as there was discussion about that and other then hard-coding a list of platforms/filesystems that allowed locks, they settled on the unsupported exception. There was talk about this as the only way to test it would be try/catch on a lock and handle your code path based upon what the OS provides, i.e. maybe your DB needs to use an exclusive connection, handle it via pseudo locks, etc...

Comment: `or else we should be getting a lot more complaints` I didn't even know this method exists, or I probably forgot about it. I've been using C# since 2002 and run a .NET meetup. I wouldn't even think of taking file locks in a web application anyway as this would be a *great* way to deadlock. I'd use pub/sub mechanisms instead, perhaps using a BackgroundService with a queue, to avoid the need of locking entirely. Locks seriously harm scalability and concurrency

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, it's an embedded database library not specifically for a web app (and originally for .NET Framework), and there's no central server process to coordinate access, so it uses that locking primitive to negotiate concurrent access between multiple processes.  But we are thinking about options for a future redesign.

Comment: @RobParker so you have the same problem LiteDB has? Redesign may be necessary if you want scalable concurrent writes. In SQLite for example, writers append changes to the Write Ahead Log and a checkpointer moves those changes to the database file when needed. More advanced databases like SQL Server Compact tracked table, page, row locks just like the server versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check [the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/IO/FileStream.OSX.cs) you'll see that this is *explicitly unsupported*. The version-specific `FileStream.OSX.cs` file explicitly throws :

```
public partial class FileStream : Stream
{
    private void LockInternal(long position, long length)
    {
        throw new PlatformNotSupportedException(SR.PlatformNotSupported_OSXFileLocking);
    }

    private void UnlockInternal(long position, long length)
    {
        throw new PlatformNotSupportedException(SR.PlatformNotSupported_OSXFileLocking);
    }
}
```

The nice thing about GitHub is you can use [blame](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blame/a9f3fc16483eecfc47fb79c362811d870be02249/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/IO/FileStream.OSX.cs#L11) to find out when that file changed and how.

The [commit comment](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/commit/0daa63e9ed40323b6f248ded8959530ea94f19aa) three years ago (February 2017) explains why this was turned off:

> OSX doesn't support usage of both fcntl and flock. Since we're already using one in FileShare for the entire file, we cannot enable partial file locking like we do on other Unix platforms. The alternative is to throw a PNSE and suggest using FileShare on the whole file instead.

Comment: Thanks for digging that up!  If it's generally disabled for MacOS then I guess we'll have to adjust how we handle it for that specific runtime.  Fortunately, we just added a single-process mode which uses in-memory locking, so we aren't far from an alternative solution.